# Matplotlib.pyplot: How to set up a second y-axis for an existing plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have two sets of values that are linearly dependent. Therefore I just need a single graph with a second y-axis in the right scale.

> What is the most elegant way to do this?

Making just two bar-plots gives me an overlap:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = np.arange(4)
y2 = np.array([23, 32, 24, 28])
y1 = 4.2 * y2

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y2) 
ax.set_ylabel('Consumption in $m^3$')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(x, y1, alpha=0.5) 
ax2.set_ylabel('Consumption in EUR')

plt.savefig('watercomsumption.png', format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image: example-plot]

Thanks alot! :-)

---

**EDIT**:

I might have been unclear. I would like to make a *single* graph.
Something like the following. But is there a more elegant way than calling the bar-function twice and hiding it with `alpha=0`?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(4)
y2 = np.array([23, 32, 24, 28])
y1 = 4.2 * y2

y2max = np.max(y2) * 1.1

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y2)
ax.set_ylabel('Consumption in $m^3$')
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax2.bar(x, y1, alpha=0)
ax2.set_ylabel('Consumption in EUR')

ax.set_ylim(ymax=y2max)
ax2.set_ylim(ymax=4.2*y2max)

plt.savefig('watercomsumption.png', format='png', bbox_inches="tight")
```

[image: example-code2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to call `bar` twice and only want the second y axis to provide a conversion, then simply don't call bar at all the second time. You can still create and adjust the second y axis *without* actually plotting anything on it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(4)
y2 = np.array([23, 32, 24, 28])
y1 = 4.2 * y2

y2max = np.max(y2) * 1.1

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6,6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.bar(x, y2)
ax.set_ylabel('Consumption in $m^3$')
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax2.set_ylabel('Consumption in EUR')

ax.set_ylim(ymax=y2max)
ax2.set_ylim(ymax=4.2*y2max)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the effort but this is not what I was looking for. I might have been unclear with my question but I am searching for a way without calling the bar-function twice. I added an other example above! Again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @smoneck Updated in the second part. Simply don't call `bar` and only alter the ylims.

Comment: Changing the question qualitatively is very unfortunate but anyway thanks a lot for the hint—that did it! It's always the most obvious you don't notice… Or what's in the fridge in front in the middle. :-)